# Go to marker when click on Button

Tags: c#, android, google-maps, xamarin

I writing Android app

I created map with markers.

Code:

```
private void SetUpMap(){

        if (mMap == null) 

        { 
            FragmentManager.FindFragmentById<MapFragment> (Resource.Id.map).GetMapAsync (this);
        }
    }


    public void OnMapReady (GoogleMap googleMap)
    {
        mMap = googleMap;

        LatLng latlng = new LatLng (50.412300, 30.522756); 
        LatLng latlng2 = new LatLng (50.423831, 30.463489);
        LatLng latlng3 = new LatLng (50.439924, 30.592327);
        LatLng latlng4 = new LatLng (50.401984, 30.636648);
        LatLng latlng5 = new LatLng (50.431346, 30.517219);
        LatLng latlng6 = new LatLng (50.457135, 30.383227);
        LatLng latlng7 = new LatLng (50.430409, 30.385552);
        LatLng latlng8 = new LatLng (50.504091, 30.513835);
        LatLng latlng9 = new LatLng (50.461769, 30.520406);
        LatLng latlng10 = new LatLng (50.378065, 30.457423);
        LatLng latlng11 = new LatLng (50.516691, 30.617218); 
        LatLng latlng12 = new LatLng (50.397940, 30.638287); 
        LatLng latlng13 = new LatLng (50.451535, 30.525201); 
        LatLng latlng14 = new LatLng (50.445590, 30.495336); 
        LatLng latlng15 = new LatLng (50.452749, 30.515953); 
        CameraUpdate camera = CameraUpdateFactory.NewLatLngZoom(latlng,10 );
        mMap.MoveCamera (camera);

        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions ()
            .SetPosition (latlng)
            .SetTitle ("МУРАКАМІ ТРЦ «ОКЕАН ПЛАЗА»")
            .SetSnippet ("Вс. - Чт. 10:00 - 00:00  Пт. - Сб. 10:00 - 02:00");

        MarkerOptions options2 = new MarkerOptions ()
            .SetPosition (latlng2)
            .SetTitle ("МУРАКАМІ НА ЧЕРВОНОЗОРЯНОМУ")
            .SetSnippet ("Пн. - Вс. 11:00 - 00:00");
```

I have activity with list of places.

I need to tap button and it will open activity with map and go to specified marker.

How I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the below code in the OnClick event of specified button

```
 // change the latlng to your specified latlng
 CameraUpdate camera = CameraUpdateFactory.NewLatLngZoom(latlng,10 );
 mMap.MoveCamera (camera);
```

Comment: I have latlng and button in different Activities @Waleed Sarwar

Comment: If they are in different activities you can create an intent and add two extras containing longtitude and latitude, and when your map activity starts check for those values and if present and valid, use the code from Waleed Sarwar.

Comment: @Eugene glethien is right.Pass the lat long in the extras of intent get the value from intent in next activity when you press the button